# Disable JavaScript in WKWebView - Preferences not saving in WKWebView

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I am making an app where the user can click a button to disable all JavaScript **on the next page load** (not to restart the app to take effect). I tried the following code but the preferences are not saving. JavaScript is still enabled on the next page load.

```
let preferences = WKPreferences()
preferences.javaScriptEnabled = false
webView.configuration.preferences = preferences
webView.reload();
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have directly disable `javaScriptEnabled` to false and it is working fine for me. I have tested with [JavaScript Website](https://www.javascript.com/). In that I have enter my name and it change background colour based on javascript. After disable javascript, I have tried again and there are no background colour display.

```
webView.configuration.preferences.javaScriptEnabled = false
```

Try with above code, I hope it will help you also.

Comment: @Bob, Pleasure to help you.